# How do I prevent Evolution calendar notifications?

Tags: gnome, 17.04, notification, evolution, calendar

I'm primarily using Gnome Calendar (on Ubuntu 17.04). Some more complex Calendars cannot be set up in Gnome Calendar, so I installed Evolution, set up my calendars there and now they show up fine in Gnome Calendar as well.

My problem is, that I get all calendar notifications twice. Once from Evolution and once from Gnome Calendar. I only want the Gnome Calendar notifications.

How do I prevent Evolution from showing the notifications?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the change can be made in:

```
preferences -> calendar & Tasks -> Reminders
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this is in the preferences for Evolution under the "Edit" menu.