# Turn off calendar notifications - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: notification, calendar

My Google calendar notifications keep popping up. Every single one of them. I have turned off Firefox notifications in the Settings menu. I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940946/how-do-i-prevent-evolution-calendar-notifications) but there is no preference menu in my Ubuntu 20.4.

Example:

[image: Example]

Please, does anyone know how to turn off the calendar pop ups?

Comment: This notification is caused by the `evolution-data-server` package, but DO NOT TRY TO REMOVE IT! Both `ubuntu-desktop` and `gdm3` depend on it and you will boot to a text shell the next time you reboot

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with Firefox notifications.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you added online accounts, go to `settings > Applications > calendar`, then turn off notifications

Or you can go to `settings > online accounts > google account` the calendar option

Comment: This didn't work for me in Ubuntu 20.10

Comment: The calendar option is not available in my Applications tab. Deactivating the calendar option in the Google Account did not change anything.

Comment: sometimes it can be other things. If you don't want them at all, try https://askubuntu.com/a/1297664/1025264.

Comment: I can confirm this works for me in 20.04.

Comment: Doesn't do anything in Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: In 23.10 settings App -> Calendar "notifications" to off does not disable this pop up window.

Answer (score 25):

You can suppress the ugly pop-up window – but keep the less obtrusive Gnome Shell notification – by setting **/org/gnome/evolution-data-server/calendar/notify-with-tray** in [dconf](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/dconf).

I discovered this from a [comment](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution-data-server/-/issues/60#note_947191) in a related evolution-data-server bug report ([GNOME/evolution-data-server#60](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution-data-server/-/issues/60)).

#### Option 1: Use dconf Editor

Install dconf Editor if it's not already installed:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Launch dconf Editor:

[image]

Navigate to **/org/gnome/evolution-data-server/calendar** and set **notify-with-tray** to "on":

[image: dconf-notify-with-tray]

#### Option 2: Use `gsettings`

Alternatively, a quicker way to turn this setting on is to issue following command in the terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.evolution-data-server.calendar notify-with-tray true
```

Comment: This didn't work for me (either via the dconf GUI or gsettings) in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does not work in Ubuntu 20.04 either for me

Comment: I tried option 1 in Ubuntu 23.10 and that seems to have disabled the reminder pop up window.

Answer (score 14):

Currently it's the way how evolution notification daemon is working. If u want to disable just reminders, but keep notifications you can do it by so:

- Copy the file `/etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.Evolution-alarm-notify.desktop` to your local `.config/autostart` folder.
- Open the copy with a text editor, and change the line `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;XFCE;Dawati;MATE;` to `NotShowIn=GNOME;`

Now keep in mind, that you can replace `GNOME` by any distro you're using.

You need to log out then back in for the change to take effect.

Comment: It would be nice to disable just the sound, as it makes an annoying alarm clock sound.

Comment: I think you need to log out and log in again for the changes to take effect.

Comment: In Ubuntu 21.04, the instructions are the same, except you only need to add the line `NotShowIn=GNOME`. You don't need to delete the existing line as it doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 10):

Switch of the notifications of "Evolution Alarm Notify" without any need to open scripts or files just like so:

1. Search for `Notifications` in Ubuntu's search bar (hit the windows key), which is a menu point of the `Settings`. It looks like

[image]

2. Click on "Evolution Alarm Notify", which looks like

[image]

3. Switch off as per your preferences.

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Sure seems like it should, though.