# Ubuntu 22.04 Can't disable annoying Evolution Reminders despite having disabled it (and Calendar Reminders as well) in Settings?

Tags: evolution

I have tried to disable Evolution Reminders and disable Calendar Reminders both in Settings, but to no avail. I have also tried changing the configuration file setting for Evolution to add the setting for ignoring reminders for GNOME - but to no avail. There seems to be no mention of this annoying issue in the 22.04 release of Ubuntu. This used to be working just fine (ie no reminders! I use Thunderbird and am very happy with its reminders) before 22.04 upgrade. Clearly something has changed but unfortunately I cannot find any clear tips/suggestions on the web on how to revert it back to no reminders now. Please help! - Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After searching for a solution for a **looong time** and going through lots of questions in askubuntu and trying their proposed solutions, nothing worked for me...

Until I read the answer above from Naveen and I was able to configure Evolution Alarm Notify to stop popping up those annoying reminders!!

I read the [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238826/turn-off-calendar-notifications-ubuntu-20-04) Naveen mentioned above. I did not try the step that worked for Naveen, as it did not seem to make sense to me. **BUT** I first tried the answer that explains how to configure the setting **notify-with-tray** in **org.gnome.evolution-data-server.calendar**. I tested it and it seems to work for me (for now ) !!!

This is how the setting looks like after configuring it.
[image]

You can also configure it via the terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.evolution-data-server.calendar notify-with-tray true
```

Many thanks to [Naveen](https://askubuntu.com/users/752096/naveen) and [Arthur](https://askubuntu.com/users/57751/arthur-blair) for their help!

Comment: This seems to be working for me, thanks for the answer! Somehow even removing access to my online accounts didn't do the trick.

Comment: You are welcome, I am very happy to have helped out 

Answer (score -1):

I was finally able to get rid of these reminders using tips from [Turn off calendar notifications - Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238826/turn-off-calendar-notifications-ubuntu-20-04)

In particular the step:
Copy the file /etc/xdg/autostart/org.gnome.Evolution-alarm-notify.desktop to your local .config/autostart folder.

is the one that made the difference. I had to make sure that the evolution notification daemon stops creating notifications for my GNOME desktop.

Comment: explain: "I had to make sure that the evolution notification daemon stops creating notifications for my GNOME desktop."?   The only step you describe explicitly did not make any difference for me.

Comment: Follow the steps described in the link that I had followed (it is also posted in my response above - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238826/turn-off-calendar-notifications-ubuntu-20-04). I had to re-do this recently upon latest Ubuntu 22.10 upgrade and it worked again for me.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu 22.04 - I'm not sure yet but in thunderbird preferences (thunderbird > preferences > addons and themes > eds calendar integration) that looks like the culprit. I'll report back if if I'm wrong.

Comment: Welcome to AU. I think it’s better to try your strategy out then post an answer you have confidence in rather than one you aren’t sure about and will come back to if it doesn’t work.